# Install4J fails to startup on Mac OS X

Tags: install4j

With [JabRef](http://www.jabref.org/), we experience a weird situation where some users get the following error when starting JabRef

[image: error message]

We do not ship a JRE with our application and rely on that Java is installed on the machine of the users.

We have a long [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/3587) about this particular error and despite all our efforts, it seems we cannot find the source of the issue. Especially, since none of the devs can reproduce it. Fortunately, one of the users who experiences this error was kind enough to provide all information about his machine:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

$ which java
/usr/bin/java

$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 74 Aug 14 12:09 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java

$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
1.8.0_161, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_121, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home

$ echo $JDK_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I asked this particular user to provide the `INSTALL4J_LOG` and so that we can compare the log-files of Install4J on [my machine](https://hastebin.com/dasiqoromo.js) where it works and on the [users machine](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/files/1656982/JabRefLog.txt) where it fails.
My machine runs OS X 10.13.2 and the system of the user is OS X 10.12.6.

There are two main differences between them. The first difference is that when I invoke the JabRef launcher, it instantly tells me the order of places to search for Java:

```
2018-01-24 02:10:14.437 JavaApplicationStub[4846:345347] -[Launcher findJavaBundle:] [Line 479] search sequence (
    EPATH,
    Y,
    "EJAVA_HOME",
    "EJDK_HOME"
)
```

This is exactly the order we have configured in Install4J

[image: img]

On the users log-file this part is missing completely. However, it doesn't really matter, because the JRE/JDK is very rarely included in the `$PATH` variable. The next things to check are the *default locations* and this will find the JRE in `Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin` first. 
Therefore, on my machine and on the users machine, JabRef will use this JRE and not any of additionally installed JDK's.

Now, there is the probably more important difference. On the machine of the user, it seems the JRE needs to be unpacked which does not happen for me:

```
2018-01-23 12:27:08.320 JavaApplicationStub[40695:1133965] -[Launcher findJavaBundle:] [Line 474] Running unpacker
2018-01-23 12:27:08.323 JavaApplicationStub[40695:1133965] +[Unpacker unpack:withProgress:] [Line 24] found ()
2018-01-23 12:27:08.323 JavaApplicationStub[40695:1133965] +[Unpacker unpack:withProgress:] [Line 24] found ()
```

After that, the logs look similar but when finally the JRE is invoked, it cannot be found on the user's machine and we get the error message

```
2018-01-23 12:27:08.328 JavaApplicationStub[40695:1133965] int launcher_main(int, char **) [Line 925] Could not load JRE from The bundle “Java SE 8” couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located..: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ff882cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffa4d9e48d objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff90006c3d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   JavaApplicationStub                 0x0000000100008644 -[Launcher launch] + 468
    4   JavaApplicationStub                 0x0000000100008ef5 launcher_main + 645
    5   JavaApplicationStub                 0x0000000100009062 main + 34
    6   JavaApplicationStub                 0x0000000100001504 start + 52
)
```

Now, I'm not sure why unpacking is necessary and if it can be explained by the particular JRE or the different Mac OS versions.

In any way, I have asked the user to install the Oracle JRE 1.8.0_161 so that we both have the exact same Java and I'll report back if this solved the problem.

However, has someone a bright idea why the Install4J launcher crashes?

Comment: To get debug information, execute `INSTALL4J_LOG=yes /Applications/JapRef.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub`. Also, the directory listing of `/Applications/JabRef.app/Contents/Plugins/jre.bundle` would be interesting. Does deleting the bundle and reinstalling solve the problem?

Comment: @IngoKegel I already have provided a link to a text-file with the install4j-log. Please see the paragraph that reads "and in addition to that, he turned on logging and provided the log-file of Install4J which can be found here". I'm checking the dire of `jre.bundle` and report back.

Comment: @IngoKegel You might have misunderstood the situation. This error appears when users start the installer. They never make it to the point where `JabRef.app` is installed on the system. I have made this more clear in my first paragraph and I added an additional information section at the end.

Comment: The screen shot does not appear to be from the installer, though. Can you do me a favor and write an email to support@ej-technologies.com, referencing this question?

Comment: @IngoKegel You might be right indeed. I was under the impression that the failure happens when running the installer because in the issue it was mentioned several times that the "`dmg` does not run". If it is indeed the installed application that fails, I have of course several ideas how to proceed. I'm clearing this up and if push comes to shove, I'm going to write to support. I will report back. Thank you in any case!

Comment: @IngoKegel I have almost completely rewritten the question. You were right that the launcher (and not the installer) fails. I have included as much information as I could and provided the log-file for the failing machine and for my machine where it works. Can you take a look at it and confirm that I still should send an email to support? Maybe you can explain the issue with the additional information.

Comment: Yes, please send a short email to support, I would like to assign it to somebody who does not post here.